# Display div on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link `id="show"` in header and a div `id="display"` in footer. I want to display div `id="display"` when mouse hover on `id="show"` that is in header area and div is in footer area.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<header>
<a href="#" id="show"><span> Show Div </span></a>
</header>
<---- Other Content -->
<footer>
<div id="display"> --- Content --- </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: "mouse hover on `id="login"`"?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ & http://api.jquery.com/show & http://api.jquery.com/hide

Comment: mouse hover on id="show"?

Answer (score 2):

Try this : You can use `.hover()` function as shown below. Pass comma seprated functions to it. First function to call when `mouseover` and second for `mouseleave` event.

```
$(function(){
  $('#show').hover(function(){
     $('#display').show();
   },function(){
     $('#display').hide();
  });
}):
```

Answer (score 1):

Without JQuery:

```
document.getElementById('show').onmouseover = function(evt) { 
   document.getElementById('display').style.display = "inline";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/rxffwyux/

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <a href="#" id="show"><span> Show Div </span></a>
</header>
<---- Other Content -->
    <footer>
        <div id="display"> --- Content --- </div>
    </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
#display {
    display: none;
}
```

**Js**

```
(function() {
        $(function() {
            //On Dom Ready
            $('body').on({
                mouseenter: function() {
                    $('#display').show();
                },
                mouseleave: function() {
                    $('#display').hide();
                }
            }, '#show');
        });
    }());
```